# WP multisite to phpBB bridge

Tags: wordpress, phpbb

This has been discussed before but it looks like a lot of things have changed recently and most answers no longer apply.

Does anyone know of a way to link/bridge the user databases of phpBB and WP? For the purposes of this question i do not (necessarily) mean single sign on or sharing topics, simply that a user created in the WP frontend will have user access to phpBB and vice versa (a user created in phpBB will be added to WP user database).

There are a number of plugins out there that can 'sort of' do this. However, few will work for WP multisite. The (one?) that did has recently disappeared and most of the other plugins seem to no longer be under development (eg WP-united).

Does anyone know of either a plugin or way to do this manually?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to know this as well. my site has been broken since the WP 4.0 update